# Flask Socket IO encryption

Tags: python, swift, encryption, flask, socket.io

How to encrypt everything that passes through socket between my server and clients? I'm using Flask's socket.io on server and Swift socket.io on clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the secure `wss://` (WebSockets over SSL/TLS) protocol instead of `ws://`. Just like `https://` it is also encrypted. If you are using `https://` by default you can only use `wss://`.